# Java difference between static and final static variable initialization

Tags: java

```
public class StaticTest {

    private static StaticTest stObj=new StaticTest();
    private static int VAR1=10;
    private static final int VAR2=20;

    public StaticTest() {

        System.out.println("Var1 : "+VAR1);
        System.out.println("Var2 : "+VAR2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("VAR1 after constrution : "+StaticTest.VAR1);
    }

}
```

Output :

Var1 : 0
Var2 : 20
VAR1 after constrution : 10

Why is this different behavior for VAR1 and VAR2 ?

Comment: VAR2 is a constant value but VAR1 is a simple static variable. That means VAR1 will be initialized after stObj is initialized. That's why VAR1 is 0 [default int init value] at the first call, and 10 after the second call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VAR2` cannot be changed one the class has been initialised, whereas any instance of the class can change `VAR` later on.

The issue here is that you're referring to the variable before it has been fully initialised.

```
private static StaticTest stObj=new StaticTest();
private static int VAR1=10;
private static final int VAR2=20;
```

You're creating an instance of the class when loading the class itself, before the other static members have been initialised.

Check the [Java Language Specifications for more details (Chapter 12)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4).

(Generally, creating an instance of the class during its own construction will lead to problems: you should avoid this.)

Comment: But nobody is changing any variable ?

Comment: The variable `VAR` is initially `0` before it can be set to `10`.

Answer (score 5):

The static fields get initialized one by one in order of declaration. 
In your particular case you initialize `StaticTest stObj` first. This gets executed before the initialization of the `VAR1`. Thus `VAR1` bears its default value when printing.

However `VAR2` is compile-time constant, thus the compiler optimizes its initialization and it is initialized first. That way one of the variables is initialized by the time you call the constructor, the other -not.

Answer (score 3):

`VAR2` is a compile-time constant, so its value is "baked in" to every call site. It therefore doesn't matter that you use it before you would *expect* to see it initialized. If you change it to something which *isn't* a constant as far as the compiler is concerned, e.g.

```
private static final int VAR2 = "xyz".length();
```

then you'll see the same behaviour as for `VAR1` (in terms of the output).

See [section 15.28 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) for more information about constant expressions.

Comment: So you mean to say at compile time VAR2 is assumed as constant?

Comment: @amicngh: It's not a matter of *assumption* - it's a matter of following the JLS. The variable is static and final, it's of a primitive type, and the initialization expression is a compile-time constant expression; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28

Comment: @JonSkeet, you're right, but I think there's more to it in this question (regarding initialisation order).

Comment: @Bruno: Well my answer is about why VAR1 and VAR2 behave differently. I was hoping the OP could figure the rest out - Boris's answer covers it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

`VAR1` can be changed, `VAR2` can't.

Try this:

```
private static int VAR1=10;
private static final int VAR2=20;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    VAR1 = 25;
    VAR2 = 35; // You'll find a compilation error here.
}
```